# how to pass value from dropdown ng-change event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i want car_id how to get car_id from dropdown and pass to ng-change event please help me

```
 <select   ng-change="carsCtrl.ok(car_id)">
     <option ng-repeat="item in carsCtrl.current_job.cards">
  {{item.brand}}   {{item.last_digits}}
     </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: The `ng-change` directive only works with the `ngModelController`. Add an `ng-model` directive to instantiate the `ngModelController` and specify the scope variable.

Comment: Did you check documentation ?  'ng-model' holds selected option. You can pass ng-model variable to the ng-change function. Here is a simple example https://plnkr.co/edit/pur3pnWciWBtNHBQj60v?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that you need is add a ng-model directive for the ng-change. After that you can the variable added in the ng-model in the function that you want to call on the ng-change directive, like:

html:

```
<select ng-change="check()" ng-model="cardSelected"><option ng-value="item.id" ng-repeat="item in cards">{{item.brand}}</option></select>
```

controller:

```
$scope.cards = [
    {id: 1, brand: 'Brand1'},
    {id: 2, brand: 'Brand2'},
    {id: 3, brand: 'Brand3'}        
];

$scope.check = function () {
  console.log('cardSelected', $scope.cardSelected);
};
```

Comment: You can use the directive ng-value="item.id" in the options. Im going to update the code